# Catch all Subdomains in one PHP-File

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have a Domain, lets say "example.com" and a Server running CentOS and Apache

On my Server I have a Webpage that works just fine but I want to catch all Subdomains in one PHP-File:

test.example.com/test --handled by--> example.com/subdomainhandler.php?requested=test.example.com&file=test

But I don't want the User to notice it in his Adress-Bar!

I know that there can be Wildcards in DNS-Records, but then I can just get it to map the requested file directly to my existing Webpage.

Is there any way to do this without a second phisical Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with an [alias directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Alias). Also, if you're using an SSL certificate, don't use wildcards. They're not safe. Set a subject alternative name (SAN) instead.

You can also do this via mod_rewrite. 
For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.example\.com
RewriteRule  ^(.*)\.example\.com example\.com/subdomainhandler.php?requested=$1&file=test  [P]
```

You'll might need to modify the regex to meet your needs.

Source: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url

Comment: But how exactly can I map all Subdomains to one File with this?

Comment: @Unkn0wnCat You create an alias for /test in your main config file that points to the file on your filesystem. If a path ends with that, it should map to the file.

Comment: But test is only a placeholder! I want *.example.com/* to be handled by that file

Comment: See edits above.